# Trying to put the for i+ inside a mysql query, php wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, wordpress, pdo

Do you guys have any way to put the for i+ inside a mysql query or any way to make strings depends on the amount of array?

The reason I have to do it because I use wordpress and I have to implode an array with the IN(). Unfortunately, if I have to use `$wpdb->prepare`, and I need to use %s, if I use %s, my string have to match the %s. Of course, I can use foreach, but then the query will be call hundred times if my array have hundred value. And, if I don't use `$wpdb->prepare`, I don't have problem either, but it's not secure.

I was thinking PDO, but I am not so familiar with PDO, and I think `$wpdb->prepare` is more secure than PDO. So, I am struck here. trying to figure out a way to dynamically create string base on array amount.

Any ideas, appreciate.

```html
<?php

$arg = array('a','b','c');//i don't use foreach because my array is so long that will call query hundred times.

$t= implode(',', array_fill(0, count($arg),'%s'));
$sym = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("
SELECT DISTINCT disease FROM dis WHERE disease IN ($t)
" ,for( $i= 0 ; $i <= count($arg); $i++ )
{
echo $arg[$i];
}));


?>
```

Comment: `$wpdb->prepare("query", $args)`?

Comment: Not working. Like I said, if I have three %s, then the string $args have to be three, $args,$args,$args, that's why I want to use for i+

Comment: According to manual https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/ you __can__ pass values as array as a second argument. So the error is somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you very much for the article. You are right, it is somewhere else. I keep digging the wrong hole. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you are trying to use `$wpdb->prepare` for security reasons but I think `$wpdb->prepare` is not suitable for your case. You are creating a large query string and you seem to have problems with this function. The wordpress docs states that `$wpdb->prepare` is not suitable for all cases. Let's look for an alternative while making sure it is secure enough for our query. If we browsed `esq_sql` doc

> In 99% of cases, you can use $wpdb->prepare() instead, and that is the
>   recommended method. This function is only for use in those rare cases
>   where you can't easily use $wpdb->prepare().

And I think we have one of these rare cases and we can't easily use `$wpdb->prepare()`

> Note: Be careful to use this function correctly. It will only
>   escape values to be used in strings in the query. That is, it
>   only provides escaping for values that will be within quotes in the
>   SQL (as in field =  '{$escaped_value}').

And our values are within quotes so we meet this condition

> If your value is not going to be within quotes, your  code will still
>   be vulnerable to SQL injection. For example, this is  vulnerable,
>   because the escaped value is not surrounded by quotes in the SQL
>   query: ORDER BY {$escaped_value}. As such, this function does not
>   escape unquoted numeric values, field names, or SQL keywords.

And this warning is not for our case.

For these reasons I think you can use `esq_sql` in your case without compromising security. Something like this should work:

```
<?php
$arg = array( 'a', 'b', 'c' );
$arg_str = " ";

foreach ( $arg as $val ) {
    $arg_str .= "'" . esc_sql( $val ) ."', ";
}
// Remove the last comma
$arg_str = substr ( $arg_str, 0, strlen( $arg_str ) - 2 );

$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT DISTINCT disease FROM dis 
                               WHERE disease IN ( " . $arg_str . " )" );

?>
```